# How to disable all ui elements in video.js

Tags: jquery, css, video, video.js

I simply want an autoplaying looping video using video.JS with no ui elements (i need to support IE8). I've just started working with video JS and it seems very well thought out, so i have feeling there's a cleaner method (or setting in the JS) for achieving this that doesn't involve me manually setting everything in the css to display:none;. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

so far i have no clue how to do this in jw player but you could always use the video tags in HTML5 and it would look something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
</head>
<body> 
    <video width="" height="" controls> // if you dont want controls delete the controls attribute
        <source src="yourvideo.*" type="video/yourvideoformat" />
    <video>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `controls` attribute to disable controls; add `autoplay` and `loop`.

```
<video id="my_video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
preload="auto" width="480" height="264" poster="poster.jpg"
data-setup="{}" autoplay loop>
```